# PSHostUserInterface and Windows 10/PowerShell 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, windows-10

we're currently working on an application that hosts a PowerShell runspace/pipeline and executes PowerShell scripts. Now there's something my colleague and I noticed which we can't explain.

The PSHostUserInterface interface exposes [different methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface_methods(v=vs.85).aspx) to write console output to, specifically in this case `Write(ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor, String)`, `Write(String)` as well as `WriteLine(ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor, String)`,`WriteLine(String)`and `WriteLine()`.

These methods are called as soon as a script writes something to the PowerShell host, for example a simple `Write-Host "Hello World!"`. Now the problem here is that our code behaves differently while running unit tests on my and my colleague's PC. The difference seems to be that I recently upgraded to Windows 10 (PowerShell 5.0) while he's still running Windows 8.1 (PowerShell 4.0). (This is just what we think is the cause, it could be something else though). The project runs with .NET 4.5.1

They behave the following way:

**Windows 8.1 (PowerShell 4.0)**

`Write-Host "Hello World!"` -> Calls/triggers `Write(ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor, String)`with the for-/backgroundcolor and the string value (Hello World!) first and then `WriteLine(ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor, String)` with the colors and empty string value, which should represent a newline.

`Write-Host "Hello World! -NoNewLine` -> Calls/triggers `Write(ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor, String)`with the for-/backgroundcolor and the string value (Hello World!) only.

**Windows 10 (PowerShell 5.0)**

`Write-Host "Hello World!"` -> Calls/triggers `WriteLine(ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor, String)`with the for-/backgroundcolor and the string value (Hello World!) only. There's also no appended newline.

`Write-Host "Hello World!" -NoNewLine` -> Calls/triggers `WriteLine(ConsoleColor, ConsoleColor, String)`with the for-/backgroundcolor and the string value (Hello World!) only. Also no newline here (which shouldn't be of course).

---

That is the basic problem. It seems like under Windows 8.1 the framework is executing and triggering the right methods for the Write-Host cmdlet but it's different with Windows 10/PowerShell 5.0. We're just talking about carriage returns, but when writing the output to a list and using that list for further processing, I'm sure most of you can imagine that this is a problem.

Does anyone has experienced the same behavior? Is this a bug in the new PowerShell? Why is this happening?

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me. I have an app that hosts PowerShell, it will be affected... Unfortunately I cannot play yet with v5 otherwise I would investigate and report to [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback).

Comment: so basically the difference is that write / write (new-line) changed to writeline?  Doesn't writeLine take care of the newline that the second write did?  I see that it's different, but seems like it would work out the same.

Comment: I think so, too, I posted the same question in the MS forums - maybe I'll get some feedback there. But I'll also report it to Connect, thanks for the tip.

Comment: BTW, I am running a custom host with PowerShell 5.0 and the write-host handling didn't seem to change.

Comment: I take back my "sounds like a bug". "Bug" is a bit too strong. But this is still a change that may affect applications that host PowerShell. Obviously it did, hence the question.

Comment: @MikeShepard Well, maybe it's intentional, if I get any answers elsewhere, I'll post them here. It's somehow strange, though - if you think about the Console.WriteLine it appends a newline after your string, which it doesn't (seem) to do on PS5. It also does exactly the same when calling `Write-Host "Test"` and `Write-Host "Test" -NoNewLine` - I don't think that's right, the difference should be the carriage return :)

Comment: Oh and we also implemented our own custom host for this application, we're only using the PSHostUserInterface.

Comment: @DangerousDetlef - I get different results with and without -NoNewline.  Namely, one gives a newline and the other doesn't.

Comment: Could it be because of the new colored syntax highlighting that the new v5.0 console has? They definitely had to make some changes to the PSHost to allow that?

Comment: @MikeShepard Interesting, so how do they behave? `Write-Host "Test"`calls `Write(..)` and then `WriteLine(..)` and with the `-NoNewLine` it calls only `Write(..)` like with PS4.0?

Comment: I'm not running the debugger right now, but I get a newline when I use Write-Host "test".  If I say -NoNewLine, I don't.  It looks to me like it's working the same as 4.0.

Comment: @DangerousDetlef A more "deterministic" way to answer this is to look at de-compile of the code that invokes the `PSHost` implementation using .NET Reflector or similar. There are several free de-compilers available. I've been using JetBrains for example. If there is a check for Win 10 (or other version) it should stick out pretty clearly. You could start de-compilation with the `write-host` implementation (`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand` on PS 3.0; `gcm write-host|select *` to view)